# Can attributes be nillable in XSD 1.0?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.0

I have a case where an attribute is 1) not required, 2) when used can take on .i) null or empty or .ii) a version-string which will be verified (I hope) with a regex.

Regarding 2.i, How can I create an attribute that is nillable? I haven't seen this yet during my brief time with xml & xsds

EDIT: Adding example of what I'm talking about, where "attribute_1" corresponds to my situation

```
<xsd:element attribute_1="x" attribute_2="y" />
<!-- or -->
<xsd:element attribute_2="y" />
<!-- or -->
<xsd:element attribute_1="" attribute_2="y" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a complex type for your element and declare the attribute as "optional", something like this:

```
<xs:element name="tElementType">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="myelement" type="xs:string"/>           
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="myattribute" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>-
<xs:element name="thisIsMyRealElement" type="tElementType" />
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_example.asp

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Ah, but passing an empty value is different from having an attribute present or not.  use="optional" is necessary, but not sufficient.

I did some reading and here's what I found:  

Using minLength="0" for some reason doesn't work, but using <xsd:pattern value="x|" /> allowed for value x, or null. Between pattern and use, I was able to validate :D

Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

In XSD, 'nillable' is a technical term applicable only to elements; nillability allows elements whose types would otherwise require that they have content to be valid even if empty.  So the answer to your question as posed is "no, attributes cannot be nillable".

What you describe, on the other hand, is an attribute which can be unspecified (which you can achieve with `use="optional"` on the attribute declaration) and which allows the empty string as a valid value (which is already a property of xs:string).  So the answer to the question "can I make an attribute omissible and valid when specified with the empty string?" is "yes."

Since "" is a legal value for xs:string, neither `minLength="0"` nor the pattern you specify should be necessary; if you have a validator that rejects the empty string for attributes typed as xs:string, you have a broken validator.